# paramiko - error with a large wget command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

this is my code:

```
import paramiko
import time

host = "123.456.789"
username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"

client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
_stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command("sudo -i")
_stdin.write(password + '\n')
_stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command("sudo wget -O- 'https://abc.com.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda", get_pty=True)
_stdin.flush()
#Print content
for line in _stdout.readlines():
   print(_stdout.read().decode())
# Close ssh connect
time.sleep(5)
client.close()
```

the result I get is the screen doesn't print anything, and after a period of ~30-40 minutes the server doesn't receive any files from the wget command....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to invoke the Shell instead:

```
import paramiko, time

host = "123.456.789"
username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
remote_shell = client.invoke_shell()

remote_shell.send("sudo -i")
remote_shell.send(password + "\n")
remote_shell.send("sudo wget -O- 'https://abc.com.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda")

# print reply
time.sleep(1)
print(remote_shell.recv(65535))
time.sleep(1)
client.close()
```

Comment: this is code working, thank you:
remote_shell.send("sudo -i" + "\n")
 remote_shell.send(password + "\n")
 time.sleep(2)
 remote_shell.send("wget -O- 'abc.com' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda"  + "\n")